# Files lost after checkouting out to the other branch

Tags: git, git-stash, git-checkout

I want to apply the same changeset onto two different branches.

Here's what I do:

```
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m "initial"

git branch other

touch file2
git add file2
git stash

git checkout other
git stash apply

git checkout master
git stash apply
git stash drop
```

And that works. file2 exists on both branches. But if I change to the other branch and then back to master, file2 does no longer exist on master anymore! Why is it happening and what can I do about it? I also have one limitation: I cannot call git commit on master branch after applying stashed changes.

git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git stash apply` only applies changes to the working tree and index, *not* to the repository.  So when you `git checkout` a different branch before committing, you lose those local modifications.  If you want them to persist on that branch, you *have* to commit to the branch.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to commit after all

Answer (score 0):

That works for me.

A better way to apply the same changeset is likely to:

1. `git commit` your changeset on `master`.
2. `git checkout other`
3. `git cherry-pick master`

Comment: Thanks Len. I'm not sure if cherry-picking a stash is even possible. Even though I can't create commits on master as I mentioned, I still tried your idea with creating a commit on master cherrypicking it later onto the 'other' branch. After that, I called 'reset HEAD^' to undo the commit keeping files but the same problem is still there: if I checkout the 'other' branch I loose those files on the master branch.

Comment: What does it mean to apply a changeset to two branches without committing? As @vergenzt mentioned, that doesn't make any sense. You can easily roll a commit back, if you need to; you could commit to both, then checkout master and say `git reset HEAD^`; that'll roll back the commit, but leave the changes in your working tree (like a stash).